# Google Play Developer Console API - Get average review

Tags: c#, google-play

Does anyone know how to get average review using Google Play Developer Console API? I have this, and was able to get reviews; but can't seem to find how to retrieve average ratings.

```
using Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2;
using Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2.Data;
...
ReviewsResource review = new ReviewsResource(publisherService);
var reList = review.List(bundle_id);
reList.MaxResults = 15;
var reviews = reList.Execute();
...
```

[image: Code inspection]

I am hoping to get the following information,
[image: Google Play Store - Avg Rating]

My code is in C#, but if you have leads in any other language, it's fine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I been working on exact same thing recent couple days, and as far as I can see, no, at least I cant find any 'official' way to get that average number.

What I have done, is to use the same API you are using (Python version though) to get the latest reviews, note that, this API does not contain any review without comment, meaning that if your user simply rate stars without saying any word, those kind of reviews are not include in the result of this API. And, this API only gives you the reviews in last 7 days, beyond that, you have to go 'Ratings' or 'Reviews' in your console, the up right corner there is a 'Download' link, from where you can download monthly report files, in CSV format, if you got [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) installed you can also get those files with a script. Note that, this CSV report still does not contain all the reviews, according to my case, it has only 95~97% of all, no idea why... And, it does not like the API gives you very details device metadata like Android OS version, screen dpi, phone brand, etc...too bad, but unfortunately this is the only way we get all reviews in history.

So, that's basically how I did it, a script fetching latest review every hour, save them into database (also i post a webhook notification to my team slack when we get 1 star review). Another script fetching csv files every day, and detect duplication by testing time with second and nona. Note that, you'd need a Service Account for those script, you definitely don't want your script stop working like every day or week because of the expired OAuth token.

Then I can get that average number from my own database, and lot more other analytics chart by using [metabase](http://www.metabase.com/)...

Such a long journey, isn't it? And good luck!